# Selenium WebDriver Automatically Throws TimeoutException - C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

We are currently migrating our automation scripts from Selenium RC to WebDriver.  I've run into a few issues with WebDriver, mainly dealing with TimeoutExceptions being thrown the instant something in the web page being tested is changed.

For example, I am currently logging in on a page, then clicking a submit button, which redirects to a new page.  The instant the click() method is invoked the exception is thrown.  However if I stay focused on the password field and use SendKeys(Keys.Enter) the redirect works without any issues.

Has anyone else ran into this?  Since the exception is thrown when the click method is invoked, I cannot set any wait or timeout period directly after.  I know I can swallow the TimeoutException, but surely there has to be a better solution.

I am using the Firefox driver.  I am guessing the issue has something to do with the pages' source being changed.

Here is the exception:

[image: TimeoutException]

Here is the click method:

```
public void ClickByName(string name) 
{ 
    _driver.FindElement(By.Name(name)).Click(); 
}
```

Comment: I use Selenium with FireFox driver a lot where i work, and this never happens. Maybe it's something else that's causing it. It's not the redirect itself. How is the page being redirected ?

Comment: Have you tried using Explicit and Implicit Waits ? http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

Comment: @gillyb I was wondering if it was something with my FirefoxProfile instance or the version of Firefox I am using.

Comment: @PaniKumar I have tried using these waits, but the page is already fully loaded when the click event is invoked.  The event goes through, because I can watch the page redirected in the browser however the exception is thrown in the code somewhere in the API code for WebDriver.Click().

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the version. We used to use FF version 6, and recently we updated to a newer version, not really sure. The only difference i know of though is that some operations don't work that good with newer versions sometimes, things like 'hover', but nothing you should be worried about.

Comment: @gillyb I reverted to Firefox 14 and the click method is not giving me issues anymore.  I am still having issues with selecting dropdown items on a page.  This is due to other elements changing on the page depending on what is selected in the dropdown.

Comment: Stupid question: The actual click is succeeding though, but then you get the exception?

Comment: @AllanChow Yes.  The actual event executes and you can see the change reflected in the browser.  That's why if I swallow the exception I can have the tests execute normally.

Comment: Stupid question 2: What version of Firefox Driver are you using?  For what it's worth, here's a link to the Changelog:  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: If you've reverted down to a previous build of Firefox and you had an uptodate copy of Selenium, I'd get the Selenium developers in and raise an issue over at there Google Code page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a sleep statement after logging in to the page, before checking for page errors and this fixed the problem, as well as InvalidOperationExceptions being thrown occasionally.